# assignment may update an object not in the enclosing context's modifies clause

Tags: dafny

```
  datatype CACHE_STATE = CACHE_I| CACHE_S| CACHE_E
  datatype NODE_CMD = NODE_None| NODE_Get| NODE_GetX
  datatype UNI_CMD = UNI_None| UNI_Get| UNI_GetX| UNI_Put| UNI_PutX| UNI_Nak
  datatype INV_CMD = INV_None| INV_Inv| INV_InvAck
  datatype RP_CMD = RP_None| RP_Replace
  datatype WB_CMD = WB_None| WB_Wb
  datatype SHWB_CMD = SHWB_None| SHWB_ShWb| SHWB_FAck
  datatype NAKC_CMD = NAKC_None| NAKC_Nakc
  type NODE=nat
type boolean=bool

class  class_0  {
var 
Cmd : NAKC_CMD
}


class  class_1  {
var 
HomeProc : boolean,
Proc : NODE,
Cmd : SHWB_CMD
}


class  class_2  {
var 
HomeProc : boolean,
Proc : NODE,
Cmd : WB_CMD
}


class  class_3  {
var 
Cmd : RP_CMD
}


class  class_4  {
var 
Cmd : INV_CMD
}


class  class_5  {
var 
HomeProc : boolean,
Proc : NODE,
Cmd : UNI_CMD
}


class  class_6  {
var 
HomeInvSet : boolean,
InvSet : array<boolean>,
HomeShrSet : boolean,
ShrSet : array<boolean>,
ShrVld : boolean,
HomeHeadPtr : boolean,
HeadPtr : NODE,
HeadVld : boolean,
Dirty : boolean,
Local : boolean,
Pending : boolean
}


class  class_7  {
var 
CacheState : CACHE_STATE,
InvMarked : boolean,
ProcCmd : NODE_CMD
}


class  class_8  {
var 
NakcMsg : class_0 ,
ShWbMsg : class_1 ,
WbMsg : class_2 ,
HomeRpMsg : class_3 ,
RpMsg : array<class_3 >,
HomeInvMsg : class_4 ,
InvMsg : array<class_4 >,
HomeUniMsg : class_5 ,
UniMsg : array<class_5 >,
Dir : class_6 ,
HomeProc : class_7 ,
Proc : array<class_7 >;
constructor(invmsg:array<class_4 >,unimsg:array<class_5 >,rpmsg:array<class_3 >,proc:array<class_7 >){
NakcMsg := new class_0 ;
ShWbMsg := new class_1 ;
WbMsg := new class_2 ;
HomeRpMsg := new class_3 ;
RpMsg := rpmsg;
HomeInvMsg := new class_4 ;
InvMsg := invmsg;
HomeUniMsg := new class_5 ;
UniMsg := unimsg;
Dir := new class_6 ;
HomeProc := new class_7 ;
Proc := proc;
}
}


class TopC{
var
Sta : class_8 ;
constructor (){
var
invmsg:array<class_4 >,unimsg:array<class_5 >,rpmsg:array<class_3 >,proc:array<class_7 >;
Sta := new class_8 
(invmsg, unimsg, rpmsg, proc);
}
}

method n_NI_ShWbinv__4_0(top:TopC,N0:nat,p__Inv4:nat)
//requires top!=null
//requires top.Sta!=null
//requires top.Sta.Dir!=null
requires N0>0
requires top.Sta.Dir.InvSet.Length==N0 
ensures top.Sta.Dir.InvSet==old(top.Sta.Dir.InvSet)

requires N0>0
requires top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet.Length==N0 
ensures top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet==old(top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet)
//ensures top.Sta.Dir==old(top.Sta.Dir)
requires N0>0
requires top.Sta.UniMsg.Length==N0
requires forall i,j::0<=i<top.Sta.UniMsg.Length&&0<=j<top.Sta.UniMsg.Length==>top.Sta.UniMsg[i]!=top.Sta.UniMsg[j]
// ensures top.Sta.UniMsg==old(top.Sta.UniMsg)top.Sta.Dir.HomeShrSet
requires forall i::0<=i<top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet.Length
==>top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet[i]!=top.Sta.Dir.HomeShrSet

requires  p__Inv4<N0
requires (!((top.Sta.HomeProc.CacheState == CACHE_E) && (top.Sta.UniMsg[p__Inv4].Cmd == UNI_PutX)))//statement has nothing with prop--it guranttee itself
//guard condition
requires   (top.Sta.ShWbMsg.Cmd == SHWB_ShWb);
// ensures   (!((top.Sta.HomeProc.CacheState == CACHE_E) && (top.Sta.UniMsg[p__Inv4].Cmd == UNI_PutX)))
modifies top.Sta.Dir.InvSet
modifies top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet
modifies top.Sta.Dir
modifies top.Sta.ShWbMsg
modifies top.Sta 
modifies top 

{
  top.Sta.ShWbMsg.Cmd := SHWB_None;
  top.Sta.Dir.Pending := false;
  top.Sta.Dir.Dirty := false;
  top.Sta.Dir.ShrVld := true;
  
  var p:=0;
  while(p<N0)
    decreases N0-p
    invariant top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet==old(top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet)
    invariant top.Sta.Dir.InvSet==old(top.Sta.Dir.InvSet)
  {  //assume 0<p<=top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet.Length;
     //assume 0<p<=top.Sta.Dir.InvSet.Length;
     aux1(p,N0,top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet.Length);
     aux1(p,N0,top.Sta.Dir.InvSet.Length);
      if (((p == top.Sta.ShWbMsg.Proc) && (top.Sta.ShWbMsg.HomeProc == false)) || (top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet[p] == true)) {
        top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet[p] := true;
        top.Sta.Dir.InvSet[p] := true;}
  else{
        top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet[p] := false;
        top.Sta.Dir.InvSet[p] := false;
      }
  p:=p+1;
  }
  //assert top==old(top);
 // assert top.Sta ==old(top.Sta );
  //assert top.Sta.Dir==old(top.Sta.Dir);
  if ((top.Sta.ShWbMsg.HomeProc == true) || (top.Sta.Dir.HomeShrSet == true)){
    top.Sta.Dir.HomeShrSet := true;
    top.Sta.Dir.HomeInvSet := true;}
  else{
    top.Sta.Dir.HomeShrSet := false;
    top.Sta.Dir.HomeInvSet := false;
  }
  
}

lemma aux1(p:int, N0: int, M:int)
requires 0<=p<N0
requires N0==M
ensures 0<=p<M
{}
```

Dafny tell me that  "top.Sta.Dir.HomeShrSet := true; " statement assignment may update an object not in the enclosing context's modifies clause. I guess that

1. the error occurs due to the fact top.Sta.Dir.HomeShrSet is not in the range that modifies cause defines;
2. I have defined that modifies top.Sta.Dir.InvSet

   modifies top.Sta.Dir.ShrSet
   modifies top.Sta.Dir
   modifies top.Sta.ShWbMsg
   modifies top.Sta
   modifies top
3. how to define modifies clause to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your `modifies` clause is fine. To fix this problem, you need to add this line to your `while` loop:

```
invariant top.Sta.Dir == old(top.Sta.Dir)
```

The line `modifies top.Sta.Dir` tells Dafny that whatever object `top.Sta.Dir` refers to *at the beginning of the method* may be modified. However, without this extra invariant, Dafny doesn't know that the value `top.Sta.Dir` hasn't changed by the point in the program where you execute `top.Sta.Dir.HomeShrSet := true`.